# Как поставить точку на яндекс карте, через PHP свойства

Tags: php, html, битрикс, yandex-maps-api

В шаблоне страницы нужно вывести яндекс карту с динамическими точками на ней, которые подтягиваются из свойств. Вроде бы всё написал верно, но, почему то, карта не выводится, если ставлю заместо координат те самые свойства. Подозреваю что ошибка чисто синтаксическая. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

ymaps.ready(init);

function init() {
    var myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
        center: <?=$arResult['PROPERTIES']['MAP']['VALUE']?>,
        // Уровень масштабирования. Допустимые значения:
        // от 0 (весь мир) до 19.
        zoom: 12,

            })

    });



    var myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark(<?=$arResult['PROPERTIES']['MAP']['VALUE']?>,);

    myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);

}
```

Comment: А почему бы не использовать компонент  map.yandex.view ?
У него в настройках компонента поставьте сначала одну точку. затем откройте скрипт страницы где был вызван компонент и посмотрите как там координаты встали. И сделайте их динамическими там

Answer (score 0):

Синтаксис в Яндекс картах должен быть вот таким:

```
var myMap =
  new ymaps.Map("map", {
     center: [num1, num2]
```

Не знаю как выглядит ваше значение $arResult['PROPERTIES']['MAP']['VALUE'], если это массив, то должно быть что-то вроде этого

```
new ymaps.Map("map", {
     center: [<?= $arResult['PROPERTIES']['MAP']['VALUE'][0] ?>, <?= $arResult['PROPERTIES']['MAP']['VALUE'][1] ?>]
```

Comment: center: не точка на карте а только смещение так сказать. 
Чтоб карта к примеру смотрела сразу на Москву, а не по умолчанию